# jQuery scroll event doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar

I am developing a small jQuery function to run when the scrollbar is at the bottom of the page, but I have a few problems.

**PROBLEM 1**

When I resize the page (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>) the function stops working. It works correctly again when the zoom is set to 100% (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>).

**PROBLEM 2**

On mobile devices it never works. I have been reporting on this and it seems that the scroll event works differently in web browsers than in mobile browsers.

This is my code:

```
$(window).on("resize scroll", function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() == $(document).height()){
        $("body").css("background-color", "green");
    }
});
```

I use the jQuery 2.1.3 library.

Is there a way to make my code compatible for all browsers and devices and solve the problem of resizing the page?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Guess you might be interested in [`.scrollstart`](https://api.jquerymobile.com/scrollstart/)...